# Cannot access WebUI of secondary router set up as WAP (DD-WRT)

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have followed the "official" wiki guide to set up a DD-WRT router (Netgear WNR2000v2) as a WAP and I can successfully connect to the internet afterwards: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

- Local IP Address: 192.168.1.2
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway/DNS: same as primary/upstream router

However, I'm unable to connect to the WAP webUI! Before it was reachable at 192.168.1.1 but since I applied the new WAP settings I'm unable to connect through here or 192.168.1.2 (new local ip address).

After I run a "route -n get default" when connected to the WAP and then to the primary router, I see that although the resulting gateway ip addresses are different, the first one is redirecting to the second, which is the primary router login page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This was posted on SO but deleted by the author, which is why it looks like a copy/paste.

Comment: @music2myear yes! realised it wasn't the right place...

Comment: No worries. We get suspicious when the question starts with the voting button text. I removed that and added the comment so others wouldn't flag the question for this reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason you're having this problem is that you don't have the IP address of the secondary router. This can be an issue when you have two routers and one of them is doing some sort of pass-through and the other is running DHCP. What you want to do it assign static IPs to any secondary routers on your network, and so long as those IPs are in the same subnet as the rest of the network you should be able to access the the control UIs for them just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the primary router, so I cannot assign it a static ip. I think I'll try to separate the subnets.

Comment: Hi @Tim_Stewart the basic setup shows what I wrote in the first post and it's a Netgear WNR2000v2 with DD-WRT r33413. I tried reboot yeah. But the good news is that when I tried having separate subnets, the gateway remained on the secondary router (rather than redirecting to primary) and still have internet access. So I'll go with this! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I tried separating the subnets, following the same guide posted before: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

In this case the gateway remained on the secondary router rather than redirecting to the primary.